# Strange behaviour with base class constructor and data member initialization

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I've got a really big and strange problem with one of my C++ programs (here's the source code: https://github.com/dermesser/libsocket).

First, some details around it:
There's a base class (socket, in C++/socket.cpp), a (virtual) derived class (unix_socket, in C++/unixbase.cpp) and a "leaf" class (unix_stream_server). The data member "sfd" is declared and initialized in "socket" (socket.cpp). But in unix_stream_server::setup (C++/unixserverstream.cpp), "sfd" has got a completely different value. A little bit debugging output:

```
socket constr -1 # <--- "socket" constructor
unix_socket constr - sfd: 1447345536 # <---- unix_socket constructor
setup final: 1447345536 # <--- unix_stream_server::setup
unixserverstream.cpp:76: unix_stream_server::setup: Socket already set up!
```

The last line is the error message passed by the exception. Debugging the program gives the same results.

The strangeness is that the value of the variable varies widely and I can not figure out why. And in sibling classes with similar inheritance path, this problem does not exist.

Edit 1: The problem doesn't even disappear if I reassign "sfd". It simply remains at the same strange value.

Some problems I eliminated and things I tried:

- Definition/Declaration mismatches (I know, this is quite strange in this software)
- Putting "sfd" to the public area

What could also matter: The problem exists if I link the program (it's examples++/unix_server_stream.cpp) statically or dynamically (against the SO generated by the Makefile).

I'm desperate :( Does anyone have ideas or experience with such problems? Or am I too tired to find the solution?

Edit 2: It's difficult to post code. I think it's better if you follow my hints to the files on the github repository, because I don't have an idea which part to post. :| Sorry... (And please don't think that I want you to work for me - it's only difficult to select the right code)

unix_stream_server::setup():

```
if ( sfd != -1 )
        throw socket_exception(__FILE__,__LINE__,"unix_stream_server::setup: Socket already set up!\n");
if ( path == NULL )
        throw socket_exception(__FILE__,__LINE__,"unix_stream_server::setup: Path is NULL!\n");

    sfd = create_unix_server_socket(path,STREAM,flags);

    _path.assign(path);

if ( sfd < 0 )
        throw socket_exception(__FILE__,__LINE__,"unix_stream_server::setup: Error at creating UNIX   stream server socket!\n");
```

Comment: Post code, not words :-)

Comment: I would say that `sfd` is uninitialized, based on the value.

Comment: If you explicitly call the parent class constructors in the sub-class constructors (i.e. `unix_socket::unix_socket(void) : socket::socket(), _path("") {}` and similar for `unix_stream_server`) does it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header has `bool listening` in the definition of `class unix_stream_server`, but your `.cpp` file has another definition of `class unix_stream_server` which omits the `bool listening` member.  Don't do that.  Seriously, don't do that.  Include your headers from your implementation files!  Please!

Comment: Thank you very much :D It was like I said, too tired to find such bugs. And yes, I'll change that with double-declaration, it's the worst idea I've ever had and I already had several problems with it. :)

Comment: The best problem was a SIGSEGV because of a virtual base class declaration mismatch :P